# Parse Json with more than one object Java

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am using son to parse data into classes, now I have a more dimensional José which I need to parse.

```
{
  "Preisanpassung" : {
    "PA_ARTIKEL" : [
      {
        "PA_EKB" : 0,
        "PA_EAN" : 0,
        "PA_NVK" : 0.0,
        "PA_NR" : 0,
        "PA_AVK" : 0.0,
        "PA_SOLLBEST" : 0,
        "MENGE" : 0,
        "ARTBEZ" : "",
        "REDUART" : ""
      },
      {
        "PA_EKB" : 0,
        "PA_EAN" : 0,
        "PA_NVK" : 0.0,
        "PA_NR" : 0,
        "PA_AVK" : 0.0,
        "PA_SOLLBEST" : 0,
        "MENGE" : 0,
        "ARTBEZ" : "",
        "REDUART" : „0“
      }
    ],
    "PA" : [
      {
        "PA_NR" : 0,
        "PA_GUELTIG_AB" : 0
      },
      {
        "PA_NR" : 0,
        "PA_GUELTIG_AB" : 0
      }
    ],
     "PA_EKB" : [
      {
        "PA_NR" : 0,
        "PA_EKB_BEZ" : "",
        "PA_EKB" : 0
      },
      {
        "PA_NR" : 0,
        "PA_EKB_BEZ" : "",
        "PA_EKB" : 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I use following class models for the parsing process:

```
public class Preisanpassung implements Serializable {
        public Preisanpassung(List<PA_ARTIKEL> paartikel, List<PA> pa, List<PA_EKB> paekb) {
            this.PA_ARTIKEL = paartikel;
            this.PA = pa;
            this.PA_EKB = paekb;
        }


        private List<PA_ARTIKEL> PA_ARTIKEL;
        private List<PA> PA;
        private List<PA_EKB> PA_EKB;

    public Preisanpassung() {

    }

public class PA implements Serializable {
    private long PA_GUELTIG_AB;
    private  int PA_NR;

    public long getPA_GUELTIG_AB() {
        return PA_GUELTIG_AB;
    }

    public void setPA_GUELTIG_AB(long PA_GUELTIG_AB) {
        this.PA_GUELTIG_AB = PA_GUELTIG_AB;
    }

    public int getPA_NR() {
        return PA_NR;
    }

    public void setPA_NR(int PA_NR) {
        this.PA_NR = PA_NR;
    }
}
```

The classes PA_Artikel and PA_EKB are build like the class PA.

Compiler shows no error and son throws no exception. Is there any way to parse this Json correctly?

I've also tried to split the output into multiple strings, which works well but takes a lot of time.

Comment: Learn about Java naming conventions and    @SerializedName

Comment: use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to create model classes from your Json structure.

Answer (score 0):

There are unexpected character in your json.

i.e. In your second `PA_ARTIKEL` object `"REDUART" : „0“` is invalid.
Try changing it.

Comment: Why should it be invalid? it is a String with the character 0 in it.

Comment: @FabianGr No it isn't, that are invalid quotation marks.

Comment: try to change „0“ to "0" in this part - "REDUART" : „0“